# Utilizing the Websocket Data from Android cellphone while running

Tags: python, android, websocket, position, polygon

Using [SensorServer](https://github.com/umer0586/SensorServer), I am establishing a connection between an android phone and Python and utilizing the data sent. The accelerometer of the Android device is used to determine a polygonal position.

SensorServer Code:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_message(ws, message):
    values = json.loads(message)['values']
    x = values[0]
    y = values[1]
    z = values[2]
    print('x =',x,'y = ',y,'z = ',z)

def on_error(ws, error):
        print("error occurred")
        print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_code, reason):
        print("connection close")
        print("close code : ", close_code)
        print("reason : ", reason  )

def on_open(ws):
    print("connection open")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://192.168.0.101:8081/sensor/connect?type=android.sensor.accelerometer",
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever()
```

The 'x-axis', 'y-axis', and 'z-axis' are my primary uses. But I have difficulty using the data due to two main limitations:

The first, is manipulating the data while the program is running - say something like this:

```
#Ensure that the polygon will not cross the 2:-2 outline
if x > 2:
   x = 2
if x < -2:
   x = -2
```

Second, Because of the endless loop of `ws.run_forever()` i can't run any other code that defines the polygon position:

```
polygon = visual.ShapeStim(
win=win, name='polygon',
size=(z), vertices='triangle',
ori=0.0, pos=[x,y], anchor='center',
lineWidth=1.0,     colorSpace='rgb',  lineColor='white', fillColor='white',
opacity=None, depth=-2.0, interpolate=True)
```

So, I need help in resulting those complications
Appreciating comments in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:

```py
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://10.100.102.17:8081/sensor/connecttype=android.sensor.gyroscope_uncalibrated")
while True:
    if ws.getstatus() == None:
        pass
    else:
        break
    
rc = ws.recv()
rc = json.loads(str(rc))
rc = rc['values']
    
    
polygon = visual.ShapeStim(
    win=win, name='polygon',
    size=(rc[0]), vertices='triangle',
    ori=0.0, pos=[rc[1],rc[2]], anchor='center',
    lineWidth=1.0,     colorSpace='rgb',  lineColor='white', fillColor='white',
    opacity=None, depth=-2.0, interpolate=True)
```